# I can't get the autobiographer badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

[image: autiobiographier]

I can't get the autobiographer badge even though I thought I completed the requirements.

I waited several days after meeting the requirements, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 4):

As of five hours ago, [you've been awarded the badge](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer?userid=24824):

[image]

Why it took so long, I can't say, though it's normal for certain badges to take a while to be added due to how the site's caching works. The important thing is that you do have it now.